# Drag & Drop sorting not working on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript

Currently it is possible for my users to input a string, that string gets split into words and the user can reorder those words.

the reordering works correctly when the elements are not dynamic, but the elements I am adding into the DOM are not able to be dragged and dropped.

I have double checked and all the same attributes are being applied to the dynamically created elements as the ones applied to the elements already present in the list.

Here is my code:

```js
function generateWords() {

  var inputedString = document.getElementById("stringInput").value;

  var splitStringArray = inputedString.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(splitStringArray[i]);
    document.getElementById("columns").appendChild(listItem);

    var attrClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    attrClass.value = "column";

    listItem.setAttributeNode(attrClass);

    document.getElementById("columns").appendChild(listItem);

    var headerItem = document.createElement("header");
    var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
    for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
      headerItem.appendChild(textNode);
      columns[j].appendChild(headerItem);
    }

  }
}


function enableDragSort(listClass) {
  const sortableLists = document.getElementsByClassName(listClass);
  Array.prototype.map.call(sortableLists, (list) => {
    enableDragList(list)
  });
}

function enableDragList(list) {
  Array.prototype.map.call(list.children, (item) => {
    enableDragItem(item)
  });
}

function enableDragItem(item) {
  item.setAttribute('draggable', true)
  item.ondrag = handleDrag;
  item.ondragend = handleDrop;
}

function handleDrag(item) {
  const selectedItem = item.target,
    list = selectedItem.parentNode,
    x = event.clientX,
    y = event.clientY;

  selectedItem.classList.add('drag-sort-active');
  let swapItem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y) === null ? selectedItem : document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

  if (list === swapItem.parentNode) {
    swapItem = swapItem !== selectedItem.nextSibling ? swapItem : swapItem.nextSibling;
    list.insertBefore(selectedItem, swapItem);
  }
}

function handleDrop(item) {
  item.target.classList.remove('drag-sort-active');
}

(() => {
  enableDragSort('drag-sort-enable')
})();
```

```css
#columns {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

.column {
  width: 162px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
}

.column header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
}

.column:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <ul id="columns" class="drag-sort-enable">
    <li class="column">
      <header>Not dynamic</header>
    </li>
    <li class="column">
      <header>Also NOT dynamic</header>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <form>
    Enter String to generate words:<input type="text" id="stringInput" name="stringInput" /><br/>
  </form>


  <button onclick="generateWords()">Generate Words</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `enableDragItem(listItem)` inside `generateWords()` after appending the item:

```js
function generateWords() {

  var inputedString = document.getElementById("stringInput").value;

  var splitStringArray = inputedString.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(splitStringArray[i]);
    document.getElementById("columns").appendChild(listItem);

    var attrClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    attrClass.value = "column";

    listItem.setAttributeNode(attrClass);
    
    document.getElementById("columns").appendChild(listItem);
    enableDragItem(listItem); // call it here
    var headerItem = document.createElement("header");
    var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
    for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
      headerItem.appendChild(textNode);
      columns[j].appendChild(headerItem);
    }

  }
}


function enableDragSort(listClass) {
  const sortableLists = document.getElementsByClassName(listClass);
  Array.prototype.map.call(sortableLists, (list) => {
    enableDragList(list)
  });
}

function enableDragList(list) {
  Array.prototype.map.call(list.children, (item) => {
    enableDragItem(item)
  });
}

function enableDragItem(item) {
  item.setAttribute('draggable', true)
  item.ondrag = handleDrag;
  item.ondragend = handleDrop;
}

function handleDrag(item) {
  const selectedItem = item.target,
    list = selectedItem.parentNode,
    x = event.clientX,
    y = event.clientY;

  selectedItem.classList.add('drag-sort-active');
  let swapItem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y) === null ? selectedItem : document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

  if (list === swapItem.parentNode) {
    swapItem = swapItem !== selectedItem.nextSibling ? swapItem : swapItem.nextSibling;
    list.insertBefore(selectedItem, swapItem);
  }
}

function handleDrop(item) {
  item.target.classList.remove('drag-sort-active');
}

(() => {
  enableDragSort('drag-sort-enable')
})();
```

```css
#columns {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

.column {
  width: 162px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
}

.column header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
}

.column:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="columns" class="drag-sort-enable">
  <li class="column">
    <header>Not dynamic</header>
  </li>
  <li class="column">
    <header>Also NOT dynamic</header>
  </li>
</ul>

<form>
  Enter String to generate words:<input type="text" id="stringInput" name="stringInput" /><br/>
</form>


<button onclick="generateWords()">Generate Words</button>
```